# How to make [DisallowNull] show an error for an object initializer?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nullable-reference-types

.Net Core allows you to decorate a property with [[`DisallowNull`]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.disallownullattribute?view=netcore-3.1) to tell the compiler that code is not allowed to set the property to null, even if the property itself is declared to allow it. For example:

```
public sealed class Test
{
    [DisallowNull] public string? Text { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine when you try to explicitly set the property to null:

```
var test = new Test();
test.Text = null; // Warning: "Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type".
```

However, it doesn't work if you use an object initializer:

```
var test = new Test
{
    Text = null  // No warning. I want one.
};
```

Is there any way to make the code above cause a compiler warning/error?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/40127

Comment: Ah, so it's a bug. Just have to wait for a fix, then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the fix is released, you can work around this by flipping it around:

```
public sealed class Test
{
    [MaybeNull] public string Text { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

This warns that `Text` has a default value of `null` (hence the need to suppress that with `= null!`), but otherwise seems to do what you want.

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYAYAEMEDoAiYAhgOYB2A9gM7BgDGVuAwhQCYCmAgmURAJ5UwVANyoAxGQCuECEQBGEdpnY8F7VDADM2OJiaYA3qkwns2mABZMAWQAUASkPHTLgG5EATpmCYAvJjJ2AHdMABV2GgdDMPYADx9/KRkAGkwAX1EUFxccLFi/b1xw+MyXNNRylA1tKnZedlYdGJpUIyzTAG1rIj45dgA5aQgAXTNsBCxinwNMEnZgYUxahfSCpIgAQky0oA=)